# App to get audio file information like what mkvinfo does for mkv files

Tags: sound, mkv, flac, wav

Does anyone know of an app that can get the file information of a file like flac and wav files?  An app like mkvinfo but for audio files for flac and wav files?

Thanks

An example is below of what mkvinfo shows when you choose an mkv file

```
(MKVInfo) + EBML head
(MKVInfo) |+ EBML version: 1
(MKVInfo) |+ EBML read version: 1
(MKVInfo) |+ EBML maximum ID length: 4
(MKVInfo) |+ EBML maximum size length: 8
(MKVInfo) |+ Doc type: matroska
(MKVInfo) |+ Doc type version: 2
(MKVInfo) |+ Doc type read version: 2
(MKVInfo) + Segment, size 1109980134
(MKVInfo) |+ Seek head
(MKVInfo) | + Seek entry
(MKVInfo) |  + Seek ID: 0x15 0x49 0xa9 0x66 (KaxInfo)
(MKVInfo) |  + Seek position: 4099
(MKVInfo) | + Seek entry
(MKVInfo) |  + Seek ID: 0x16 0x54 0xae 0x6b (KaxTracks)
(MKVInfo) |  + Seek position: 4249
(MKVInfo) | + Seek entry
(MKVInfo) |  + Seek ID: 0x1c 0x53 0xbb 0x6b (KaxCues)
(MKVInfo) |  + Seek position: 1109967373
(MKVInfo) |+ EbmlVoid (size: 4044)
(MKVInfo) |+ Segment information
(MKVInfo) | + Timecode scale: 1000000
(MKVInfo) | + Muxing application: libebml v1.2.0 + libmatroska v1.1.0
(MKVInfo) | + Writing application: mkvmerge v4.8.0 ('SALVATION') built on May 24 2011 03:12:58
(MKVInfo) | + Duration: 2549.380s (00:42:29.380)
(MKVInfo) | + Date: Fri Feb  7 09:22:00 2014 UTC
(MKVInfo) | + Segment UID: 0xa2 0x59 0x2c 0xd2 0x39 0xd3 0xad 0x48 0x9f 0x21 0x22 0x1e 0xfb 0x3d 0xcc 0xb7
(MKVInfo) |+ Segment tracks
(MKVInfo) | + A track
(MKVInfo) |  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
(MKVInfo) |  + Track UID: 1987891370
(MKVInfo) |  + Track type: video
(MKVInfo) |  + Lacing flag: 0
(MKVInfo) |  + MinCache: 1
(MKVInfo) |  + Codec ID: V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
(MKVInfo) |  + CodecPrivate, length 40 (h.264 profile: High @L4.1)
(MKVInfo) |  + Default duration: 33.367ms (29.970 frames/fields per second for a video track)
(MKVInfo) |  + Language: und
(MKVInfo) |  + Video track
(MKVInfo) |   + Pixel width: 1280
(MKVInfo) |   + Pixel height: 720
(MKVInfo) |   + Display width: 1280
(MKVInfo) |   + Display height: 720
(MKVInfo) | + A track
(MKVInfo) |  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
(MKVInfo) |  + Track UID: 999134339
(MKVInfo) |  + Track type: audio
(MKVInfo) |  + Codec ID: A_AC3
(MKVInfo) |  + Default duration: 32.000ms (31.250 frames/fields per second for a video track)
(MKVInfo) |  + Language: und
(MKVInfo) |  + Audio track
(MKVInfo) |   + Sampling frequency: 48000
(MKVInfo) |   + Channels: 6
(MKVInfo) |+ EbmlVoid (size: 1085)
(MKVInfo) |+ Cluster
```

Comment: file information like what?

Comment: @New USer I've added an example in the question.  Bit rate, channels, codec, sampling frequency, duration, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see some of those information in [**`exiftool`**](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

install it using

```
 sudo apt-get  install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

**Example output for an audio file:**

```
exiftool Videos/9UAasbnxGDPX.128.mp3
```

Output is

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : 9UAasbnxGDPX.128.mp3
Directory                       : Videos
File Size                       : 3.9 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:02:10 13:11:25+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : MP3
MIME Type                       : audio/mpeg
MPEG Audio Version              : 1
Audio Layer                     : 3
Audio Bitrate                   : 128 kbps
Sample Rate                     : 44100
Channel Mode                    : Joint Stereo
MS Stereo                       : On
Intensity Stereo                : Off
Copyright Flag                  : False
Original Media                  : True
Emphasis                        : None
Encoder                         : LAME3.99r
Lame VBR Quality                : 4
Lame Quality                    : 3
Lame Method                     : CBR
Lame Low Pass Filter            : 17 kHz
Lame Bitrate                    : 128 kbps
Lame Stereo Mode                : Joint Stereo
Duration                        : 0:04:15 (approx)
```

---

**Another Solution**

use **mediainfo**

```
sudo apt-get install mediainfo
```

same example as above

```
mediainfo Videos/9UAasbnxGDPX.128.mp3
```

output

```
General
Complete name                            : Videos/9UAasbnxGDPX.128.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 3.90 MiB
Duration                                 : 4mn 15s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 4mn 16s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 3.90 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r
Encoding settings                        : -m j -V 4 -q 3 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```